# update data attribute value

Tags: jquery, attributes

I'm trying to update a data-id on Edit button, but for some reason it's stay on one id, which has taken it from first pick. Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="clr_name" name="clr_name">

<button type="submit" class="btn col-xs-6 hide edit">Edit</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn col-xs-6 hide delete">Delete</button>

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td>Black</td>
        <td data-id="1" class="edit">edit</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>White</td>
        <td data-id="2" class="edit">edit</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Blue</td>
        <td data-id="3" class="edit">edit</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<p>ID: <span class="dataId"></span></p>
```

JavaScript

```
$("tbody").on("click", "td.edit", function() {
  formAction($(this).attr("data-id"), $(this).parent(), $(this).prev('td'));
});

function formAction(id, parent, prev) {
  $(".dataId").text(id);
  $("tr").attr('data-edit', null);
  parent.attr("data-edit", true);
  $("#clr_name").val(prev.text());
  $(".edit, .delete").attr("data-id", id);
}
```

[jsfiddle.net/52hyktb4/](http://jsfiddle.net/52hyktb4/)

Comment: You can post the code directly here if it is on jsfiddle, see https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it stays on one id is that you have this line in your function:

```
$(name + " .edit, " + name + " .delete").attr("data-id", id);
```

After your first click - you set the current it to **all** of the `.edit` and `.delete` elements in your document.

You can just remove this line and your code should work as you expected.

Comment: $(name + " button.edit, " + name + " button.delete").attr("data-id", id); working fine. Thx

Comment: Great :) glad I could help.

Comment: @Dekel I like you reaction to the OP comment, but I dont think he/she understood what you was saying. But your comment is very funny so I up-vote your answer just for that.